# PackageBroadcastReceiver not working after app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a PackageBroadcastReceiver running ok while the app is in the background. I need it to keep listening to packages added/removed when it is closed. But, it is not.

Is there any way to do this with a BroadcastReceiver or should I move to a service?

Here the code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.cresan.antivirus.StockingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.tech.applications.coretools.advertising.PackageBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And my PackageBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PackageBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    static IPackageChangesListener _listener;

    static public void setPackageBroadcastListener(IPackageChangesListener listener)
    {
        _listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) 
    {
         if(_listener!=null && Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(intent.getAction()))
             _listener.OnPackageAdded(intent);
        if(_listener!=null && Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(intent.getAction()))
             _listener.OnPackageRemoved(intent);

    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: please post your code and this might be what you are looking for http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/components/services.html  this would keep service running, it would just restart the service if it is closed http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: I know a service will live in the background but Broadcast Receivers seems the right choice for listening to intents. I have read that android < 3.1 BroadcastReceivers kept receiving intent notifications when in background. This seems not to be happening with latest versions. And I can't find a use case to resolve the issue in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely need to implement a background service to do this. See [the developer guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

You can then programmatically register a BroadcastReceiver in your service:

```
private PackageBroadcastReceiver packageBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.packageBroadcastReceiver = new PackageBroadcastReceiver();
    this.packageBroadcastReceiver.setPackageBroadcastListener(new IPackageChangesListener() {

        public void OnPackageAdded(Intent i) {
            //do something here- probably start an activity
        }
        ...

    });

    IntentFilter packageFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED");
    packageFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL");
    packageFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    this.registerReceiver(this.packageBroadcastReceiver, packageFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.packageBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is done this way to bind the life of the BroadcastReceiver to the Service tand not the Activity. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering broadcast receiver in service. After activity is destroyed, receiver will be destroyed to so you will not get broadcast event.